# Try Catch with Redirect on error, on talking with SQL Server Getting "Redirect loop" err

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have this issue on my site, where at random times, during first login on the page it would error on one of my calls to the Sql Server, EVEN though i had:

```
 if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }

 if (cmd.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }

    cmd.Connection.Open();
```

It would error here, claiming that the connection's current state is already Open.
At first the if() worked, then even it stopped working so i added the following:

```
try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/"); //same page
    }
```

The good news is i (and my users) don't see the error page, the bad news is i get a "the page has a redirect loop" browser error.
My question is, would adding  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); be sufficient to give the browser enough time, so it wouldn't detect a redirect loop ?
Of course any comments on the bigger problem are welcome...
Thanks!

Comment: Well the bigger problem is that your database isn't reachable, obviously. You can't mask this with a redirect, as after this redirect the issue will still be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not enough connections for every user to perform their calls.

Comment: And the issue was that you're catching `Exception` and thus hiding the true error. Had you taken that out the error might have been obvious.